# Import tablespace fails after exchange partition in MySQL (Percona Server 5.7.26-29)

Tags: mysql, import, partitioning, percona, tablespace

The situation is as follows:

I am attempting to copy a table using the export/import tablespace method. Here are the details of the source and destination servers:

Source server (srcsrv):
Large table with few hundreds of partitions `partitioned_table1`.

Destination server (dstsrv):
Not partitioned table `table1`.

The flow:

on srcsrv:

```
    1. sql> create database db1.
    2. sql> use db1
    3. sql> create table table1 (source /tmp/table1.sql when table1.sql is actually script that creates  srcdb.partitioned_table1.sql without partitions)
    4. sql> alter table srcdb.partitioned_table1 exchange partition p_XXX with table db1.table1 without validation;
    5. sql> flush tables db1.table1 for export;
    6. linux> cp /var/lib/mysql/db1/table1.ibd /tmp/
    7. sql> unlock tables;
    8. sql> alter table srcdb.partitioned_table1 exchange partition p_XXX with table db1.table1 without validation;
```

By the end we have all data “back” to `srcdb.partitioned_table1` and `db1.table1` is empty.

on destsrv:

```
   1. sql> create database db1.
   2. sql> use db1
   3. sql> create table table1 (source /tmp/table1.sql when table1.sql is actually script that creates srcdb.partitioned_table1.sql without partitions)
   4. sql> alter table db1.table1 discard tablespace
   5. linux> cp /tmp//table1.ibd /var/lib/mysql/db1/table1.ibd
   6. sql> alter table db1.table1 import tablespace;
```

At this point in time, the server is going down with:

> [ERROR] InnoDB: Trying to access page number XXX in space XXX , space name db1/table1, which is outside the tablespace bounds. Byte offset 0, len 8192, i/o type read
> . If you get this error at mysqld startup, please check that your my.cnf matches the ibdata files that you have in the MySQL server.

startup the dstsrv:
`sudo systemctl start mysqld`

After the dstsrv server restarts, `db1.table1` is in a healthy state, and the data is imported successfully.

If I take `table1.cfg` from srcsrv and use it for the import, there are no issues.

According to the documentation, there should be no need for a .cfg file for the import tablespace process, especially in my situation where it is used to speed up the data copying process and there are no chances of having incorrect metadata (since everything is created as part of the process).

Any thoughts or insights on this matter?

Thanks.

Comment: Seems like an "export tablespace" in needed somewhere.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to include it in the code section, although it should be obvious. Thank you for bringing it to my attention.
Sure, I am doing flush tables for export.
I would update the post.
However the need in cfg file for import still not clear. 

Regards

Comment: Seems to be bug: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=88418
The cfg file is nessesary.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be yet resolved bug: bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=88418 The cfg file is nessesary.